# my compiler doesn't recognize resources and ids

Tags: android, commonsware

I have used commonsware's source code to make iconic-adapter project in android(you can find the source here http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/Dynamic) but i have some problems:

`super(DynamicSample.this, R.layout.row, R.id.**lable**, items);`//it doesn't recognize "lable"

```
if (items[position].length()>4) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.**delete**);
      }
```

//doesn't recognize delete, I have copied the                                                         //proper picture in drawable-mdpi

*I appreciate your answers in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things u should notice
what is the R you have imported
it is good idea to have drawable copied in all folders or at least parent drawable directory
@id not being there please check the declaration of lable again.

Comment: please look at my project here:  http://rapidshare.com/share/D2D836090097C14F8FCA6D5C1F7725E9

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a `lable` string resource (note: this is not the spelling from my book or my code).

Beyond that, clean your project (e.g., Project > Clean in Eclipse).

Comment: this is inside my row.xml and inside LinearLayout tag yet i have problem after cleaning////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////<TextView
   android:id="@+id/label"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="25sp"
   android:textStyle="bold"/>

Comment: @commons also not in my book

Comment: @user2541758 paste your xml

Comment: @user2541758: Your XML has `label`; your Java has `lable`. These are not the same.

Comment: fixed lable but yet it doesn't recognize it, also it doesn't recognize the icons I copied in drawable folder yet

Comment: please look at my project here:   http://rapidshare.com/share/D2D836090097C14F8FCA6D5C1F7725E9